# How do I change the colour of the statusline of the currently focused window?

Tags: vim-windows, colorscheme, statusline

How do I change the colour of the statusline of the currently focused window?

I've seen colorschemes modify this. Is this some sort of highlight group? Or something else?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can change it in your vimrc. The currently focused window is highlight group `Statusline`, other windows are `StatuslineNC`.

Example for terminal Vim:

```
hi StatusLine                  ctermfg=8     ctermbg=2     cterm=NONE
hi StatusLineNC                ctermfg=2     ctermbg=8     cterm=NONE
```

For the GUI, use `guifg` and `guibg`.

Comment: gvim defaults for `StatusLine` are: `term=bold,reverse cterm=bold,reverse gui=bold,reverse`, and for `StatusLineNC` the values are `term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse`